# How to sort by the newest question?

Tags: support, api, questions, api-v2.1, sort

I'm trying to retrieve the latest questions posted in a particular tag.

What's the equivalent for:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest&pagesize=15
```

I see that v1.1 API is now obsolete and I'm having a hard time figuring out what would be the equivalent in the latest API.

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `/questions` path](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) and sort by: `creation`, `desc`.

For example:

[/2.1/questions?pagesize=15&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=php&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#pagesize=15&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=php&filter=!9j_cPmQ8n&site=stackoverflow&run=true)