# How to find questions that were posted or edited recently?

Tags: support, questions, api-v2.2, sort

The api function documented at http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions lets me list questions on a site.  How do I sort this so that I see questions that are recently posted, edited, including editing the tags, or undeleted?

I could sort by "activity", but I believe that will show questions where answers were recently posted.  Questions getting answered is a common event that would clutter the list unnecessarily, and I'm not interested in answers, because I'd like to filter questions according to the question content and tags only.

See also [How to sort by the newest question?](https://stackapps.com/q/4246/21396) , but this question differs because I *do* want to notice old questions that were recently edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really is no particularly satisfactory way to do this since all versions of `last_activity_date` conflate a question's activity with the activity of its answers.

You are going to have to fetch lots of items and filter out the chaff yourself.  There are 2 main routes you can take, `event`s or `question`s:

---

### A) Use [the `/events` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events#filter=!-*f%286qzik2j2&site=stackoverflow):

1. Use a filter that includes both the `event_type` property and the `link` property.  For example, filter `!-*f(6qzik2j2`.
2. Ignore all returned items that don't have an `event_type` of either `question_posted` or `post_edited`.
3. If the event is `post_edited`, you can tell if it's a question or answer by examining the `link`.

   **Questions** will have links like:

   ```
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/give-me-teh-codez!
   ```

   **Answers** will have links like:

   ```
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/give-me-teh-codez!/86#86
   ```

**Pros:**

- Relatively easy to discriminate question activity.

**Cons:**

- Must sift through a LOT of unwanted events.
- Only returns up to the last 15 minutes worth of events.
- Requires authorization (an `access_token`), which can be a bit of a bother.
- No prefiltering possible. EG by tag(s)

---

### B) Use a route that returns [`question`s](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question), such as `/questions` or [`/search/advanced`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search):

1. Choose a filter that returns:

   - `bounty_closes_date` (optional)
   - `closed_date`
   - `community_owned_date`
   - `creation_date`
   - `last_activity_date`
   - `last_edit_date`
   - `locked_date`
   - `protected_date`
2. Fetch the results using your desired criteria.  For example:
   [/2.2/search/advanced?q=lastactive:1d title:how&tagged=java&filter=!Pw)kHGLaaqdgnO19(Z_c)7lVTGqJzn](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=lastactive%3A1d%20title%3Ahow&tagged=java&filter=!Pw%29kHGLaaqdgnO19%28Z_c%297lVTGqJzn&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
3. Ignore `last_activity_date` at this stage (it was useful for the sort in step 2).
4. For each question, if one or more of the *other* `_date` properties meets your time criteria, then the question was edited recently.  (`bounty_closes_date` needs special handling, as it might be in the future.)

**Pros:**

- Can use much more sophisticated search criteria (tags, title, user, etc.)
- Much higher signal to noise ratio in the results.
- Can fetch unlimited results (within quota allotment), unrestricted by date.
- No OAuth needed, much simpler to code.

**Cons:**

- A bit harder to discriminate question activity from answer activity.